# How to detect forward button availability?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I would like to use navigation buttons to go back and forward in the history on an hybrid mobile app. So far, `window.history.back()`and `window.history.forward()`are working juste fine.

However, I would like to change the forward button style according to its availabilty.

How to know if the forward button is available? How to know if the user clicked on a back button on the previous page?

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell if there is forward history or not. History is a security issue because the forward history could be to a different domain (like a URL with the user's bank account number). As a result, Javascript doesn't have access to it.

You'll have to find an alternative hack to get around this. Listen for a history change event and set a state variable in your Javascript.

Comment: I was therefore thinking about recording history changes in order to deduce the use of a back button: if the current page is the same as the n-2 page, then the back button was used (and forward is available). However, to perform such a page comparison, I would have to record the page filename and all the dynamic variables in order to identify which content was actually displayed. Isn't there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: @Yako you can try using `document.referrer` to see if the user come to the current page from another page that is logically in front of it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer