# How can I check if user can navigate forward in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have two buttons: one to go back and another to go forward. I want to check if the user can go forward, and if not, I will disable the button.

For the back button, I will check if `window.history.length` is greater than 0, but for the forward button, I don't have anything to check.

There is [navigation.canGoForward](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation/canGoForward#browser_compatibility), but it is experimental and not supported by all browsers.

**RouteButtons.tsx**

```
import { BackIcon, ForwardIcon } from "@sfe/utils/icons";
import { StyledButtonsWrapper, StyledRouteButton } from "./style";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const RouteButtons = () => {
 const route = useRouter();

 return (
  <StyledButtonsWrapper>
    <StyledRouteButton
      onClick={() => route.back()}
      $disabled={!window?.history?.length}
    >
      <BackIcon />
    </StyledRouteButton>

    <StyledRouteButton onClick={() => route.forward()} $disabled={false}> // no check here
      <ForwardIcon />
    </StyledRouteButton>
  </StyledButtonsWrapper>
);
};

export default RouteButtons;
```

How can I check if user can navigate forward?

Comment: More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18919189/464538

Comment: You can ***always*** navigate forward, e.g. PUSH a new history entry. Is your question really about knowing if you are not currently at the top of the history stack?

Comment: @DrewReese If you didn't go back, you cannot go forward and yes my question is that can we see where are we on history stack to check if we are on top? because I looked everywhere and didn't get the answer that I want so I asked the question.

Comment: The typical solution is to maintain your own internal "history stack" so that you know, within your app, where the user has navigated to, including any back navigation, e.g. POP, actions. The basic question of "can I navigate forward/backward" has been asked and answered many times on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for your answer, yeah I saw those questions but mostly they were for backward, for forward I didn't see any simple solution like navigation.canGoForward and I thought there is one but it looks like there isn't, thanks anyway.

Comment: "Can I go forward" is just the opposite end of the stack from "Can I go backward", so the problem and solutions are basically identical. Welcome, by the way, hopefully this was helpful.

Comment: @DrewReese Of course it was helpful :) it's not exactly the opposite in solution, in history object we have length that shows us user has already another page that can go back to it, but we don't have directly access to that stack to check if we are on top unless we build our own stack (that is a lot of code that is not worth it in my opinion) we can't say if the length is zero user can go forward, also as mentioned above there may be bank url or ... so we can't check that 100%, All the problems come from the design team that put this button :) I mean we all have them on our browsers.

Comment: What "problem" are you trying to solve (*hopefully it's not to "trap" users on/in your app/page, that's just poor UI/UX*)? Is there anything wrong with just simply issuing the forward/backward navigation and let the browser "do its thing" and handle it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256736/discussion-between-ali-navidi-and-drew-reese).

Comment: @DrewReese It's not that much of a problem, I mean user can go forward and backward whenever it's possible, I just want to disable the button when he can't do it so the experience is a little better (instead of clicking and see no action) just to make it more obvious, I saw that we have some checks for disabling back button so I thought there should be one for forward too (shouldn't be?) but it seems like we don't have it at least not yet.

Answer (score 1):

For router changes in Next you can try to subscribe to the events of the router.

example:

```
    const router = useRouter();
     const [history, setHistory] = useState([]);
     const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(-1);
     useEffect(() => {
      const handleRouteChange = (url: string) => {
        setHistory((prevHistory) => [...prevHistory, url]);
        setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1);
      };

      router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);

      return () => {
        router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);
      };
    }, [router.events]);

  const goBack = () => {
    if (currentIndex > 0) {
      router.replace(history[currentIndex - 1]);
      setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex - 1);
    }
  };

  const goForward = () => {
    if (currentIndex < history.length - 1) {
      router.replace(history[currentIndex + 1]);
      setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1);
    }
  };
```